# Can I enchant tokens too?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it legal to cast an enchantment on a token creature in MTG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Creature" means "creature permanent", which means "creature card or token on the battlefield".

As such, an Aura with "enchant creature" can enchant a creature token.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I couldn't find the answer in the online rules at the MTG website, or anywhere else for that matter.